# How to automatically run script on Linux startup?

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, startup

I need to execute a shell script on an **Ubuntu startup**. I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS version of **Ubuntu**.

I tried many things like **rc.local**, init.d etc. but I couldn't get it work.

This is the shell script that I want to execute:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo"Hello, World"
```

Comment: How did you verify it didn't work? Your above statement is missing a space between echo and ". Assuming it was correct on your system it would just do an echo statement which you wouldn't easily see.

Comment: Should try at least a Google Search before asking https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/672379

Answer (score 2):

Just to confirm, you copied your script into `/etc/rc.local`?

You can always use `@reboot` with cron.
check this out : [crontab manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/)

Answer (score 0):

Add the command to rc.local but make sure you specify the full path of the executable.

A simple echo can go unnoticed.  Place a sleep afterward or redirect output to a file to be certain the command was executed.